How do I share .h files between different BUILD files in Bazel?
I have the .h files in a different folder compared to where the BUILD file is present. I'm making BUILD file for each module so that the module can be reused in different projects. How do I link .h files present in a different module to the one that requires it?
I tried using export files but that didn't work. I would like a way to make the path relative since it is a git repo.

A (header only) cc_library seems to be what you are looking for.
For instance if I had the following tree:
.
├── MODULE.bazel
├── WORKSPACE
├── app1
│   ├── BUILD
│   └── app1.c
├── app2
│   ├── BUILD
│   └── app2.c
└── interface
    ├── BUILD
    └── my.h

The interface/BUILD file could look like this:
cc_library(
    name = "interface",
    hdrs = ["my.h"],
    includes = ["."],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

includes will add defined search path(s) to the consumers compiler (preprocessor) invocation. Add . like in this example if you expect to include my.h, if left out, you'd need to refer to it as interface/my.h. And make sure visibility allows your consumers to depend on this lib.
Then, in either of the app BUILD files, you can simply depend on your (header only) library:
cc_binary(
    name = "app1",
    srcs = ["app1.c"],
    deps = ["//interface"],
)

Of course such cc_library could also be depended on from another bzlmod.
